# How can I intercept an sms, append a string to it, and pass it on as usual in Android

Tags: android, sms

So I have to intercept the sms part figured out, as you can see in my code below.
However I run into trouble after receiving the message.
I need help appending a String to the end of the message, and then passing it on as normal as if it were never manipulated.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="guidi.moodandroid">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".SmsBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package guidi.moodandroid;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                requestPermissions();
            }
        });

    }

    private void requestPermissions() {
        String receivePermission = Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS;
        String readPermission = Manifest.permission.READ_SMS;

        if  ((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, receivePermission) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)  ||
                (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, readPermission) !=
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
        {
            String[] permissions = {readPermission, readPermission};

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions,
                    ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

SmsBroadcastReceiver.java

```
package guidi.moodandroid;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
        if (intentExtras != null) {
            Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
            String smsMessageStr = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {
//                String format = intentExtras.getString("format");
                SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);

                String smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
//                        .toString();
                String address = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();


                smsMessageStr += "SMS From: " + address + "\n";
                smsMessageStr += smsBody + "\n";
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, smsMessageStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="guidi.moodandroid.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible on Android 4.4+, if your goal is to affect the actual SMS client.

Comment: So if that is nothe possible, is it possible to change the text wherever the messages are stored.  Where are the messages stored, do you know any good sites to learn how the sms works.  Not the permissions, or getting and receiving texts, but what happens after that.

Comment: "is it possible to change the text wherever the messages are stored" -- if you are the user's chosen SMS client, yes. Otherwise, no. "Where are the messages stored" -- in [the `Sms` provider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.html).